# Changing elements in $A$ so that $m_{ij}\neq 0.$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matlab

I have the matrices

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1\\ 0 &0& 1& 1& 0\\ 1& 0& 0& 0& 0\\ 1& 0& 0& 0& 1\\ 0& 1& 0& 1& 0\end{bmatrix}$$

$$M=A+A^2 = \begin{bmatrix}0& 2& 1& 2& 1\\ 2& 0& 1& 1& 1\\ 1& 1& 0& 0& 1\\ 1& 2& 0& 1& 2\\ 1& 1& 1& 2& 1\end{bmatrix}$$

I want to to know the minimum number of zeroes in $A$ I can replace by ones in order for $M$ to have all elements non-zero.

I created a nested for-loop, within a while loop in order to break the entire thing once the desired $M$ is constructed. Here is my code:

```
go = true;
while (go == true) 
    for i = 1:5 
        for j = 1:5
            if( A(i,j) == 0)                   
                A(i,j) = 1;                     
                M = A+A^2;
                if ((numel(M)-nnz(M)) == 0)     
                    disp(M)
                    go = false;                                            
                end
            end                                 
        end
    end
end
```

The result I get is 13 different computations of $M$ and the foor loop ends once all elements in $M$ are $6.$

What is wrong?

I've also tried this variant of while loop:

```
while (1)  
    for i = 1:5 
        for j = 1:5
            if( A(i,j) == 0)                   
                A(i,j) = 1;                     
                M = A+A^2;
                if ((numel(M)-nnz(M)) == 0)     
                    disp(M)
                    go = false;                                            
                end
            end                                 
        end
    end
end
```

but with the same result.

Comment: `go=false;` doesn't mean the program will stop at that point. It will stop the next time it tries to get into the `while` loop again, which means when all `for` loops are done anyway.

Comment: Is there an effective way to break all the loops from within like I want to do? I've seen something with flags in mathworks but I could not apply it.

Comment: This is discussed here: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/102711-how-do-i-break-out-of-nested-loops-using-the-break-command-in-matlab-7-7-r2008b

Comment: That was exactly the site/page I referred to in my previous comment. I'll give it another go.

Comment: The trick is that since BREAK can break one loop at a time, the flag dummy variable allows you to break repeatedly.

Comment: But in that example I can't see where he has his statements and such.

Answer (score 1):

By looking at the zeroes in $A+A^2$, you see that the following two changes take care of everything:
$$A = \begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 & \color{red}X & 0 & 1\\ 0 &0& 1& 1& 0\\ 1& \color{red}X& 0& 0& 0\\ 1& 0& 0& 0& 1\\ 0& 1& 0& 1& 0\end{bmatrix}$$
It's impossible to do better since one change will affect only the entries in the corresponding row and column.

---

As for the code, `go=false;` doesn't mean the program will stop at that point. It will stop the next time it tries to get into the `while` loop again, which means when all `for` loops are done anyway.

A way around is to use the BREAK command repeatedly, using a dummy variable such as your `go`, as discussed [here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/102711-how-do-i-break-out-of-nested-loops-using-the-break-command-in-matlab-7-7-r2008b). Here is how to implement it here (I don't have matlab right now so I can't test it but that's the idea):

```
go = true;
while (go == true) 
    for i = 1:5 
        for j = 1:5
            if( A(i,j) == 0)                   
                A(i,j) = 1;                     
                M = A+A^2;
                if ((numel(M)-nnz(M)) == 0)     
                    disp(M)
                    go = false;     
                    break                  
                end
             end     
             if(go==false)
             break                            
             end
         end
        if(go==false)
        break
        end
    end
end
```

**Note however that this won't give you the minimum, but only some solution.**

Comment: How do you see that those two elements take care of everything? Can you show me how to imlement the dummy variable to my code? I cant see how it should be used in my code.

Comment: @Parseval edited. "How do you see" $\to$ practice linear algebra :)

Comment: I got that answer too, as you did when I ran your code. But that does not even tell me what elements in $A$ I need to change in order get $m_{ij}\neq 0.$ And you are also not using what you referred to in the comment. The dummy variable thingy. But I understand the proceedure.

Comment: Yes I am. `go` **is** the dummy variable. If you want to know which variables to change, display $A-A_0$ where $A_0$ is a variable where the original $A$ is stored (instead of displaying $M$).

Comment: so what is $A$ then? I thought $A$ was my original matrix?

Comment: @Parseval when you do disp(M), A has changed.

Comment: Displaying $A-A_0$ gives 4 ones, meaning 4 elements have changed. This unfortunately does not answer the question I'm supposed to answer: The minimum of zeros to change. And this is also supposed to be done by matlab and not by only practicing Linear Algebra. But thanks a lot for your help and time!

Comment: @Parseval yes that was the meaning of the last sentence in my answer. Of course you can elaborate and cover all cases in matlab.

Comment: I'm simply wondering if that is necessary, a classmate said he got Matlab to compute the minimum and also display the exact elements that were changed.